# wikitude architect framework

Tags: frameworks, augmented-reality, wikitude

Does anyone know how to load the actual architect.js file. In tutorials there is a script tag with the value of source attribute equal to "architect://architect.js". What kind of url is that? Apparentrly a web browser cannot load it.

Answer (score 1):

The architect:// protocol identifier is used only when running in Wikitude World Browser, ARchitect Mobile Viewer or within the SDK. It fails in a desktop browser, which is the expected behavior.

If you want to try/test/debug your ARchitect World in the desktop browser you will have to include the ARchitect Desktop Engine (ADE) which can be found at ADE/ade.js.

Comment: As a matter of fact, i do load the ade.js in my examples. However, i still cannot get the point of testing the framework with a desktop browser, since you cannot see the camera view and events such as enterFOV, locationChanged are not triggered.
Can you briefly explain the importance of ARchitect Desktop Engine?